# How do I choose series resistor for stacked Zener diodes?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener

I have 12-30V input, and I need ~10V and ~5V. So I feel like an easy way to do this would be to stack 5.1V Zener diodes front-to-back and have taps for both of the voltages I need. Something like the image below. But, I'm having trouble determining the appropriate series resistor. I only need 4mA from the 10.2V tap and 1mA from the 5.1V tap. Any guidance would be appreciated!

[image: Image of Zener Diodes Connected in Series from Electronics Tutorials]

(Image source: [Electronics Tutorials - Zener Diodes Connected in Series](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_7.html))

Comment: That would depend on which zener you have. They need to have the rated current through them to have the rated voltage over them. Who knows if you have 5mA or 25mA zeners.

Comment: Just from a quick look, I was thinking maybe this one? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/DDZ9689-7/700115 It has a rating of IZT=50uA. Is that the rating you're talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zeners with a resistor sadly aren't the way to go here. The 12-30V input voltage range makes the resistor impractical.

Let's assume worst-case conditions: 10V at 4mA out, 5V at 1mA, 12V in. This means your resistor has to pass at least 5mA with 2V across it. Easy enough, that's 400 Ohms.

But let's now crank the input voltage up to 30 Volts. That leaves 20 Volts across the resistor, which is still 400 Ohms, resulting in 50mA flowing through it. This, in turn, means that your circuit always consumes at least 1.5 Watts (50mA at 30V) whenever it's powered on. That's most likely unacceptable. In reality, your resistor will have to be smaller than 400 Ohms because the Zeners need a minimum current to operate, making the problem even worse.

There are two-terminal constant-current LED drivers that would work nicely in place of the resistor, like the [AL5809-15](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/diodes-incorporated/AL5809-15P1-7/AL5809-15P1-7DICT-ND/5030226?cur=EUR&lang=en). Alternatively, you could use a 10V and 5V LDO regulator.

Of course, your Zeners must be able to handle the full input current (15mA in case of the AL5809-15). With 5V Zeners, that'd be 75mW of dissipation per diode. Typical Zeners are rated for at least 300mW so this will not be a problem.